# Processing tokens through Drupal Rules

Tags: email, drupal-7, token, drupal-rules

I am using the Rules module to respond to specific events and send email alerts. This part of my project works fine.

My problem is I need to include some dynamic data in the email message. For this I am using Tokens but the tokens do not get processed and replaced with the neccessary text. This means the email gets delivered with tokens in the message.

Can anyone suggest how I can solve this problem either programmatically or via some configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rules for emails also and hav not encountered any issues using tokens

This is an example of the body of the email from one of my rules

```
New Issue --> [node:url]

Title - [node:title]
Description - [node:body]
Author - [node:author]
Priority - [node:field-issue-priority]
Category - [node:field-issue-category]
```

Maybe you do not have the proper format?